# I had a question about the meaning of 'bare' in a context

Tags: adjectives, phrasal-verbs

could someone tell me that what is the meaning of the word 'bare' and the phrasal verb 'divide over' in this sentence please? Here's the sentence: "Biden lays bare Nato divide over Russian aggression against Ukraine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lay bare](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lay-bare) is a phrasal verb...

...but *divide over* is not! The headline (which I assume it is) refers to a *division* (difference of opinion) within NATO *over* (about) Russia.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, Kate.